Pattern matching with glob2rx R
I have several .txt files in a directory (filedir) which start with the following strings:
files= c('sasmin_somedata.txt','sasmax_somedata.txt','sas_somedata.txt')
s=c("sasmin","sasmax","sas") 
I would like to use s to list the three files in files.
I tried the following code:
p <- glob2rx(paste0(s, filedir))
final <- list.files(filedir, p, full.names=TRUE)
However,I keep getting duplicates of sasmin, sasmax because my current glob2rx implementation uses 'sas' as wildcard and cannot different 'sas' from 'sasmin' or 'sasmax'.

Maybe s=c("sasmin_","sasmax_","sas_")?

@Edward I would prefer to keep the names in ‘s’ as they are for subsequent use in another section of my code.

p <- glob2rx(paste0(s, "_", filedir))

@Edward this works. Can you add it as an answer, and I will accept?

It's not clear to me what the precise layout of these files is. Assuming that it's like this since you mention that filedir is a directory. I've thrown in a couple of other files just to make sure that the filtering works correctly.
└── somedata
    ├── bar.txt
    ├── foo.txt
    ├── sasmax_somedata.txt
    ├── sasmin_somedata.txt
    ├── sas_somedata.txt
    └── somedata.txt

If you want to use these prefixes as a filter
s <- c("sasmin", "sasmax", "sas")

then I'd suggest skipping the use of glob2rx and just hand-roll the REGEX.
list.files(filedir, paste(s, collapse ="|"), full.names = TRUE)

The result:
"somedata/sas_somedata.txt" "somedata/sasmax_somedata.txt" "somedata/sasmin_somedata.txt"

The reason that I suggest this approach is that your present call to glob2rx() returns a vector of REGEX and my understanding is that list.files() just uses the first of those.
